# Pyspark dataframe not printing schema

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am developing a AWS glue pipeline using pyspark and I have read a table data in program
and set it to a dataframe.
But when I want to print the schema of dataframe its not printig also I cant read the column of dataframe.

````
  target_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
            database="db1",
            table_name="price_test",
            push_down_predicate=pushDownPredicate_target).toDF()
        print("first_of_month_min_survey_date--" + str(first_of_month_min_survey_date))
        print(type(first_of_month_min_survey_date))
        target_df.printSchema() # this line not working
        target_df = target_df.filter( ( F.col("SD") >= first_of_month_min_survey_date) & 
              (F.col("SD") <=  min_survey_date ) )  # Column SD not found error is throwing```
    
    
I have checked data is present in s3 and I can query the data in Athena.
Also same code is working in lower instance where data is very less
Please help
````

Comment: condition in pushDownPredicate_target is not correct thats why  no result in dataframe- 
 pushDownPredicate_target = f"( (sd_year == {source_min_survey_Year}) and ( sd_month == {source_min_date))
sd_year is int but  source_min_survey_Year is string